# Determine $y$-coordinate of a $3$rd point from $2$ given points and an $x$ coordinate.

Tags: calculus

Consider points $A(−9,−9)$ and $C(5,−6)$. The point $B$ is on the line passing through $A$ and $C$. The $x$-coordinate of $B$is $0$. Determine the $y$-coordinate of the point $B$.

This is a Calculus $1$ question and is somehow related to the topic of Limits in Motion.

Comment: The following two things would result in more help from the community: formatting your questions LaTeX for readability, and indicating what you know and have tried so far. Just an FYI.

Answer (score 1):

We can easily find the slope of the line joining $A $ and $C $ as: $$ m= \frac {-6+9}{5+9} = \frac {3}{14} $$  Using the point slope form we then get $$L: y-(-9) =\frac {3}{14}(x-(-9)) \Rightarrow L: 3x-14y =99$$  Now as point B has coordinatesome  $(0,y) $ substitute in $L$ and easily get the answer. Hope it helps.

Comment: Just a point for the OP, this method will work if you use either $A$ or $C$. There is nothing specific about picking point $A$ over $C$. Just in case there was any confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Write the equation of the line passing through two points:

$$\frac{y-y_0}{y_1-y_0}=\frac{x-x_0}{x_1-x_0}$$

where $(x_0,y_0)=(-9,-9)$ and $(x_1,y_1)=(5,-6)$

Then plug in $x=0$ and solve for $y$. You should get $y=-\frac{99}{14}$